# Implications of using ADD COLUMN on large dataset

Tags: amazon-redshift

Docs for Redshift say:

```
ALTER TABLE locks the table for reads and writes until the operation completes.
```

My question is:
Say I have a table with 500 million rows and I want to add a column. This sounds like a heavy operation that could lock the table for a long time - yes?  Or is it actually a quick operation since Redshift is a columnar db?  Or it depends if column is nullable / has default value?

Answer (score 5):

I find that adding (and dropping) columns is a very fast operation even on tables with many billions of rows, regardless of whether there is a default value or it's just NULL.

As you suggest, I believe this is a feature of the it being a columnar database so the rest of the table is undisturbed. It simply creates empty (or nearly empty) column blocks for the new column on each node.

Answer (score 3):

I added an integer column with a default to a table of around 65M rows in Redshift recently and it took about a second to process. This was on a dw2.large (SSD type) single node cluster.

Just remember you can only add a column to the end (right) of the table, you have to use temporary tables etc if you want to insert a column somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have seen rebuilding the table works best. 
I do it in following ways

1. Create a new table N_OLD_TABLE table
2. Define the datatype/compression encoding in the new table
3. Insert data into N_OLD(old_columns)   select(old_columns) from old_table Rename OLD_Table to OLD_TABLE_BKP
4. Rename N_OLD_TABLE to OLD_TABLE

This is a much faster process. Doesn't block any table and you always have a backup of old table incase anything goes wrong